# ConcurrentModificationException with ASTTransformation (Groovy)

Tags: groovy

I'm a contributor of Vert.x for Groovy (https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-groovy) and recently see a curious behaviour regarding AST Transformation.

Until Groovy 3.0.4 the VertxTransformation class (https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-groovy/blob/3.9/vertx-lang-groovy-gen/src/main/java/io/vertx/lang/groovy/VertxTransformation.java) was working just fine. When I tried to use Groovy 3.0.5 it started to appear some ConcurrentModificationException.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1044)
    at io.vertx.lang.groovy.VertxTransformation.visit(VertxTransformation.java:82)
    at io.vertx.lang.groovy.VertxTransformation.visit(VertxTransformation.java:77)
    at io.vertx.lang.groovy.VertxTransformation.lambda$visit$0(VertxTransformation.java:68)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at io.vertx.lang.groovy.VertxTransformation.visit(VertxTransformation.java:68)
```

Below there are two links: the first one shows the project building fine with 3.0.4 and the second one failing with 3.0.5. The only thing different is the Groovy version.

1. https://travis-ci.org/github/vert-x3/vertx-lang-groovy/builds/712642226 (3.0.4)
2. https://travis-ci.org/github/aaloise/vertx-lang-groovy/builds/712638741 (3.0.5, the exception appears from line 1818 onwards)

Don't know if something changed in 3.0.5 regarding AST. I even raised an issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GROOVY/issues/GROOVY-9666). If is not a bug, but an improvement, would like some suggestions for an workaround.